# Facebook publish as page indefinitely without user login

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I want to give my app the ability to post as my own page (and app separately) and am trying to work out how best to programatically get a suitable access token. I have the following code embedded in a view, and it works, but depends on an access token I'm manually inserting for now.

```
event = Event.objects.get(pk=1)
try:
    graph = GraphAPI(access_token)
    graph.post(
                path = '/42636472/events', 
                name = event.name,
                location = event.location,
                start_time = '2012-11-04T19:00:00-0700',
                )
    print event.date
except GraphAPI.OAuthError, e:
    print e.message
```

This update from Facebook suggests that hard-coding access tokens in is unsustainable and will require regular attention:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

What are people doing in this situation, to have an app update a page belonging to the app's organisation, or just getting access_tokens giving page manage access without having anyone logging in?

Answer (score 0):

The same document you linked explains that Page access tokens will continue to be infinite if retrieved using a long-lived token for the Page's admin - see **Scenario 5**